# Different values for the same model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have companies, and every Company has many Categories
I would like to keep track of the amount of categories each company has, list-style, and increase/decrease the list on add/remove, while sorting them by that position column. Therefore each category within a Company has a Position attribute.

```
|pos|  name
  1  - cat1
  2  - cat2
  3  - cat3
```

So when I create a company I already have 2 default categories (before create, etc), and in my Category class I have:

```
  @@total_positions = 2
```

For manipulating positions on Category create I use:

```
  before_create :add_position_to_new
  before_destroy :decrement_positions

def add_position_to_new
  self.position = @@total_positions + 1
  @@total_positions = self.position
end

def decrement_positions
  @@total_positions = @@total_positions - 1
end
```

This all works fine, but all of my categories across the app have a common position counter. I would like that every company has its own @@total_position counter for their categories. Please point me into the right direction.

PS: before I used acts_as_list gem and it was working great, but then I encountered some difficulties when switching to Postgres and decided to write my own method from scratch. That way you also learn a bit more, right? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, you may keep track of the count of categories and/or companies via a many-to-many relationship.

Given the following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

You then could use `size` on any association (i.e. companies and categories) to determine the number of associated objects like so:

```
company = # a company ...
# returns the number of categories for the company
company.categories.size 

category = # a category ...
# returns the number of companies for the category
category.companies.size
```

Wouldn't this work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a `counter cache` :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Read more at section 4.1.2.3 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Essentially, a `counter cache` keeps track of the number of children that exist for an association. Every time one is created or deleted the cache is changed to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction! Quick question though - does this column store position numbers per each individual item (1,2,3,4,n) or stores the total amount of these items? Problem is that I need to sort my categories based on their position attribute

Comment: Ah, that's not really that clear in your question. In fact I'm still not exactly clear on what you mean...? Try to update your question to make that requirement clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have a model CompanyCategories with attributes :

> id, company_id, category_id

You could use the id-attribute in the increasing order instead of having a separate position column. This will work unless you want a feature to reorder them categories.